# How Can communicate one terminal to another terminal ? In same system

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I am running a cpp executable file on the terminal.
How can I pass and get the input/output from another terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're the owner of both terminals, you can do it like this.

In terminal A:

```
% tty
/dev/pts/1                      # make note of this
% while sleep 3600; do :; done  # start a command which does NOT read
```

In terminal B:

```
% cat </dev/pts/1
```

Now any line you type into terminal A will go to `cat` in terminal B.

The `while sleep 3600; ...` is to prevent the shell running in terminal A from fighting for its input with the `cat` from terminal B.

Looks totally pointless?

That's because it is. A program running in terminal B could much better communicate with another from terminal A using all kind of IPC interfaces (named pipes, unix sockets, shared memory, etc). And since you're on the same system, you could just run that program in terminal A in the first place.